# Can the Prodigals see Chimerae?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

Chimerae are products of the Dreaming or objects infused with Glamour. Changelings can see them for what they are just fine, but how does this work for Prodigals, the other supernaturals in the World of Darkness? Can they see Chimerae as normal, are they completely incapable of doing so or do they require the use of their Advantages meant for seeing supernatural things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my understanding of CtD:

Chimerae, whether objects or creatures, mirror the rules associated with Changelings. While I am currently unable to provide any hard and fast citations, I would apply the rules for Prodigals seeing Changelings to Chimerae as well.

As I recall most Prodigals do not inherently see Changelings as Changelings, and I believe that Chimerae would follow the same rules. I hope this answer helps.